# standard library factorial function .Net

Tags: c#, .net, f#

I cannot seem to find any builtin factorial function in .Net, which I find incredible strange.
In many languages, for example python, there is a factorial function in the standard libraries...

- I do not want to make my own factorial function each time I need one
  in a solution.
- I would prefer not to get some library from Nuget just to get a
  factorial function, that is just silly...
- I wish to use a factorial function in both F# and C#.

Google searches drown in people who wants to write or show how to write your own factorial function.

**Am I overlooking the factorial function, or is there really no built in factorial function in System.Math, System.Numerics or anywhere else?** *(and if no factorial function exists in any standard libraries, then what is the motivation for not having this function in any standard library?)*

Yes I know it is simple to write, and can be defined like for example

```
let rec factorial = function
    | x when x = 0 -> 1
    | x -> x*factorial(x-1)
```

But I don't want to write that every single time I need this function, and it also feels silly to make my own library just for this kind of simple function...

Comment: "There is a feature unavailable in a particular language and I neither want to implement it myself, nor use a library...."

Comment: You can use Math.NET Numerics library http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Functions.html or other freely available Math libraries for .NET.

Comment: __Maybe__ they thought it is useless, after all it would best be implemented with 297 fixed resulting numbers..

Comment: AFAIK, there is no builtin Factorial function in the .Net libraries.  The vast majority of languages, OS's, API's and RTL's do not have a Factorial function.  This is because 1) There is only one application area that I know of that commonly uses the discrete factorial function, and 2) there are many fine specialized libraries for it, and that implement the discrete factorial and, 3) it is trivial to implement, and easy in professional languages to make your own library to reuse it, and 4) it quickly overflows most representations so that there are only about 56 valid returns anyway.

Answer (score -4):

You can [utilise the `BigInteger` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.common.biginteger.factorial%28v=vs.93%29.aspx) for that

However, this should do the trick if you're interested in a perfomant solution with primitive types:

```
private static readonly int[] factorial = new int[]{
    1,
    1,
    2,
    6,
    24,
    120,
    720,
    5040,
    40320,
    362880,
    3628800,
    39916800,
    479001600,
    1932053504,
};

public static int Factorial(int x) {
    if(x < 0) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("negative faculty");
    }
    if(x >= faculty.Length) {
        throw new OverflowException();
    }
    return faculty[x];
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but someone probably did because you've ignored the question. The OP clearly says they know how to do it but want to know if it is provided somewhere in the .Net framework.